# como capturar los disparos en una diana de tiro con opencv

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, inteligencia-artificial

**Estoy tratando de realizar un detector de disparos sobre una diana con opencv que arroje el puntaje de cada disparo, todo mediante una imagen (no en tiempo real) por el momento tengo este codigo:**

```
import math
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#funcion para mostrar los puntos y la diana
def show(img, titulo, center):
    plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
    plt.title(titulo)
    #plt.plot(center[0], center[1], marker="x", color="red")
    img = cv2.circle(img, center, 3, (155,155,0), -1);
    plt.imshow(img)
    plt.show()
#funcion para encontrar el centro de la diana por el mayor contorno
def centroid(contour):
    M = cv2.moments(contour);
    cx = int(round(M['m10']/M['m00']));
    cy = int(round(M['m01']/M['m00']));
    center = [cx, cy];
    return center;

#se carga la imagen y mejoramos la perspectiva
img = cv2.imread('test.jpg')
redim = cv2.resize(img, (1050, 1050))
pts1 = np.float32([[290, 300], [790,330], [260, 770], [820, 770]])
pts2= np.float32([[0, 0], [790, 0], [0, 770], [820, 770]])
M= cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(pts1, pts2)
dts = cv2.warpPerspective(redim, M, (800, 800))
#convertimos a escalas de binario y dilatamos
B, G, R = cv2.split(dts)
ret, binaria = cv2.threshold(R, 50, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
kernel = np.ones((3, 3), np.uint8)

dilatacion = cv2.dilate(binaria, kernel, iterations=5)
erosion = cv2.erode(binaria, kernel, iterations=3)
#encontramos contornos
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(erosion, 127, 255, 0)
_, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

#cantidad de contornos y el centro de la diana
print('numero de contornos = '+str(len(contours)))

print('el centro es'+str(centroid(contours[0])))

biggest_cntr = None;
biggest_area = 0;
for contour in contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(contour);
    if area > biggest_area:
        biggest_area = area;
        biggest_cntr = contour;


big_radius = math.sqrt(biggest_area / math.pi);
print('big_radius = '+str(big_radius))



cv2.imshow('dilatacion', erosion)
#dibujammos los contornos
#cv2.drawContours(dts, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 3)
cv2.drawContours(dts, [biggest_cntr], -1, (0, 255, 0), 3);
#mostramos los resultados
show(dts, "dts", centroid(contours[0]))
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

los tipos de diana que usamos en mi pais son estas[image: diana]

y por el momento solo capturo los contornos y erosiones o dilataciones y tambien cambio la perspectiva [image: diana.procesada]

como soy nuevo en el area de opencv nose como continuar mi proyecto, acepto cualquier tipo de ayuda o informacion gracias